# How to open new window from a main window?

Tags: java, swing

I have a main window (let's call it form1) that for simplicity purposew has only one button that is supposed to launch another window (form2). When I click the button I get only the close/minimize buttons and if I set the bounds before `form2.setVisible(true)` i get an empty window of the size that I set in the bounds (form2 is not empty, is has a few elements inside).

I can't figure out why my code is not working.

```
public class Form1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Form1 window = new Form1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Form1() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {     
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 708, 557);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(201, 212, 255));
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 692, 66);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnOpen = new JButton("open form");
        btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2 ();
            form2.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnOpen.setBounds(473, 94, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnOpen);

    //more elements
    }
}



public class Form2 extends JFrame {

    public Form2() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {     
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 775, 492);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 805, 58);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(201, 212, 255));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("text");
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        //more elements
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create a Form2 instance, you create *two* JFrames, not one, one that you add all your components to, that you never display, called frame, and the other, the Form2 instance itself, that you add *nothing* to, but that you do in fact display.

```
public class Form2 extends JFrame {  // **** this guy, Form2, is a JFrame ****

    public Form2() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {     
        frame = new JFrame();        // **** but so is THIS guy, frame ****
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 775, 492);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);   // **** no, no, no, no ****
```

Solution: Don't do this. Create only 1 JFrame, add all components to it and display the same JFrame. Better still, don't create a bunch of JFrames and throw them at the user since users, in general, don't appreciate this type of program. Please see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Next, we need to talk about your use of null layouts...